# Magento 2 layered navigation attribute option sort by name not number of products

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, layered-navigation, sort, magento2.2.4

My theme is child of magento blank.
On default magento 2 layered navigation sort labels of attribute in layered navigation by Count number of products that exist with this attribute.

I need to change this  alphabetically sort order.

Example:
Colours:
  Red (10)
  Blue (3)
  Yellow (2)
Change to:
  Blue (3)
  Red (10)
  Yellow (2)

Where should I look? 
In module_layered_navigation? or Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface?  or somwhere else?

I found this in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php

```
     * Create filter item object
 *
 * @param   string $label
 * @param   mixed $value
 * @param   int $count
 * @return  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item
 */
protected function _createItem($label, $value, $count = 0)
{
    return $this->_filterItemFactory->create()
        ->setFilter($this)
        ->setLabel($label)
        ->setValue($value)
        ->setCount($count);
}
```

Maybe I could add somewhere usort:

```
usort($this, function($a, $b) {
if($a['order']==$b['order']) return 0;
return $a['order'] < $b['order']?1:-1;
```

});

Comment: it's code not working it please help me how to specific attribute option filter by alphabetically'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it works on the newest Magento 2.2.4

Sort order can be applied manually in the backend.

Edit attribute => Properties=> Sort using drag & drop

Easy way.

Comment: it's code not working it please help me how to specific attribute option filter by alphabetically use in  programatically

Comment: Do you use any extra module for layered navigation? Remember to clean cache after changing sort.

Comment: Actuall i have to use one module for layer navigation but in frontend side for brand attribute option left side not sorting alphabetically.so i need to show atoz

Comment: So this module is now enabled or not?

Comment: Yes this module enable but my question is how to sort in left side brand section inside option label alphabetically order

Comment: IN admin side i know that drag and drop option and arrange it but i need coding side.if you know please share code

Comment: I'm not sure how You get your brands:  $collection = $this->brandsCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC');
        return $collection;

Comment: you say to brand page but i am saying to left side layer navigation inside

Comment: please go thorough this question its better to understand where i need "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276392/magento2-3-0-how-to-brand-filter-sorting-left-side-layer-navigation"