# Magento2.3.0 How to brand filter sorting left side layer navigation

Tags: attributes, magento2.3, layered-navigation, filter, sorting

I am using Magento2.3.0 i need to  brand filter sorting for left side layer navigation. I attached image for layered navigation to clearly understand, where am i need.

[image]

Comment: Please reply if any one know how to sort for brand left side

Comment: can you please check with admin attribute panel move up-down. I checked in 2.3.1, its working

Comment: but my question is not admin side to move up down i need to programmatically fix this issue because if more than attribute option not every time up down

Comment: `eav_attribute_option` - check with this table. I hope its very helpful to you.

Comment: $this->_option->setValue($name);
  $this->_attributeOptionLabel->setStoreId(0);
  $this->_attributeOptionLabel->setLabel($name);
  $this->_option->setLabel($this->_attributeOptionLabel);
  $this->_option->setStoreLabels([$this->_attributeOptionLabel]);
  **$this->_option->setSortOrder(0);**
  $this->_option->setIsDefault(false);
  $this->_attributeOptionManagement->add('catalog_product', $attribute_id, $this->_option);

Comment: but please give me idea in this table what i change and apply query to sort asending order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94205/discussion-between-anas-mansuri-and-rv-singh).

Comment: if you can share code to where i put it please crearify